# Selecting vectors based on “uniqueness” requirement

Tags: r

I have a program that for a chosen number of iterations, it selects N elements from `LETTERS` at random (no replace) and combines all iterations into a main `df`. I’ve added a “uniqueness” algorithm within the program that checks for how many distinct elements of `LETTERS` exist in the current iteration compared to all previous iterations. Basically, I want each run to be “different” from the others.

For example, if the current run selected `c(A, J, C, Y, W)`, and the previous run was `c(K, M, Z, A, I)`, the number of distinct Letters would be 4 since ‘A’ shows up in each. If 4 > “A Unique Threshold”, then add it to the main df, otherwise skip to the next iteration.

I want to be clear that the following code does work, it just grows very slowly for large iterations. The most obvious reason is because for each iteration `i in 1:n`, the current `i` needs to check against `i-1` iterations. As `i` gets bigger, each iteration will take longer and longer.

Looking at my reproducible code, can anyone offer advice on how to make it faster? Are there strategies for measuring “uniqueness” that don’t involve checking against every single previous run? Thank you for your help.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame()
Run <- 100 # number of iterations
numProducts <- 5 # number of LETTERS to choose at random for each run
UniqueThresh <- 2 # i.e. need to have at least 2 different than any other
for (i in 1:Run) {
  # Make random "Product List", put into temp df with Run ID
  products <- sample(LETTERS, numProducts, replace = F)
  dfTemp <- data.frame(RunID = rep(i, numProducts), products)

  # Test uniqueness (pseudo code):
  #   Get all ID's currently in `df`. For those runIDs:
  #       Count how many LETTERS in dfTemp are in run[i] (`NonUnique`).
  #         if Unique LETTERS >= UniqueThresh  THEN rbind ELSE break unique-test and go to next i
  if (i > 1) {
    flag <- TRUE
    RunIDList <- distinct(df, RunID) %>% pull()
    for (runi in RunIDList) {
      # Filter main df on current `runi`
      dfUniquei <- df %>% filter(RunID == runi)
      # Count how many in products in current `i` are in df[runi]
      NonUnique <- sum(dfTemp$products %in% dfUniquei$products)
      TotalUnique <- numProducts - NonUnique

      # If unique players is less than threshold then flag as bad and break out of current runi for-loop to jump to next i
      if (TotalUnique < UniqueThresh) {
        flag <- FALSE
        break
      }
    }
    # If "not unique enough" then don't add to main `df` and skip to next run
    if(!flag) next
  }

  df <- rbind(df, dfTemp)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of looping through each ID in your data frame, I used `group_by` and `summarise` to compare the current "product list" to each of the past IDs.  If the number of unique letters in the list is greater than `numProducts+UniqueThresh-1` we can assume they have at least 2 (in this case) different letters than that particular ID.

```
library(dplyr)

Run <- 100 # number of iterations
numProducts <- 5 # number of LETTERS to choose at random for each run
UniqueThresh <- 2 # i.e. need to have at least 2 different than any other

#initialize: the first set will automatically be accepted.
df <- data.frame(RunID = rep(1, numProducts), prods = sample(LETTERS, numProducts, replace = F))

for (i in 2:Run) {
  # Make random "Product List"
  products <- sample(LETTERS, numProducts, replace = F)
  # Test uniqueness:
  # If "not unique enough" then don't add to main `df` and skip to next run
  if(df %>% group_by(RunID) %>% summarise(test = length(unique(c(as.character(prods),products)))>(numProducts+UniqueThresh-1)) %>% pull(test) %>% all){
    df <- rbind(df, data.frame(RunID = rep(i, numProducts), prods = products))}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is a much more simple approach! Seems like it's close to working, but I have just a couple of questions after I break down the `summarise` statement. Could you walk me through real quick on how the `LETTERS[unlist(prods)]` works exactly? No matter what my first "initialized `df`" is, when I run `LETTERS[unlist(df$prods)]`, I always get some combination of `c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")`. Is there a reason it's only taking the first 5 elements? I can tell it's close

Comment: Was an attempt to cast the factor back into characters.  I changed it to `as.character(prods)` see if that works now.  One of the problems with `data.frame` is that it sometimes changes the class of the data.  When the data frame is initialized,  `df$prods` is changed to a factor, so it needs to be cast back into character.

Comment: This problem of coerced inputs can be avoided by using dplyr's `data_frame ` instead of `data.frame`